# Drawing line on Canvas using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graphic

In my WPF program I'm using canvas as a place to render drawings so when it is in line-drawing mode any unfinished line follows mouse cursor and waiting for another click to find the ending point of line.

One visual problem is that most of the time lines doesn't follow the cursor super fast... even sometimes I can see there is a delay. It finds it anyway but it doesn't stick to moving cursor as it is done in other drawing applications e.g. autocad or soildworks ...

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Comment: You should probably write a bit more about the structure of your code and an example of the line drawing portion for others to look at, otherwise it's going to be quite difficult to guess the problem

Answer (score 0):

As @PeteBaughman said, it would help to know a bit more about your code, trying posting a sample of how you add and edit the line. One possible solution though, is, if you haven't already done so, trying capturing the mouse:

XAML:

```
<Canvas OnMouseDown="MyCanvas_MouseDown" ... />
```

Code-Behind:

```
public void MyCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
    MyCanvas.CaptureMouse();
}
```

This should ensure you're getting all the mouse events and was the solution to a very similar problem I recently had.

Regards,

Richard